# Verified domain on GitHub does not work: The custom domain `example.me` is already taken

Tags: dns, github-pages, namecheap

I followed the steps on GitHub's website by adding their four IP address records, a CNAME record pointing for my www subdomain with pointing to username.github.io, and a TXT record with custom host and value provided by GitHub.

My domain now says verified by GitHub when I look at my custom domains.

However, when I try to set it as my custom domain for the my GitHub Pages site repo, I get the following error:

```
The custom domain `example.me` is already taken. If you are the owner of this domain, check out `https://docs.github.com/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages` for information about how to verify and release this domain.
```